# simplest MiniMax algorithm for TicTacToe AI in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I was trying to get a grasp of MiniMax algorithm, and have read up on it. My initial approach was to implement a simple MiniMax algorithm, and then to add alpha-beta pruning. However this is my current code:

```
public int miniMax(char[] node, int playerNum)
{
    int victor = checkWin(node); // returns 0 if game is ongoing, 1 for p1, 2 for p2, 3 for tie.
    if(victor != 0) //game over .
        return score(victor);   

    if(playerNum == 2) //AI
    {
        int bestVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int bestSpot = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < node.length; i++)
        {
            if(node[i] != '-')
                continue;
            node[i] = getSymbol(playerNum);
            int value = miniMax(node, 1); 
            if(value > bestVal)
            {
                bestVal = value;
                bestSpot = i;
            }

            node[i] = '-';
        }
        return bestSpot;
    }
    else
    {
        int bestVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int bestSpot = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < node.length; i++)
        {
            if(node[i] != '-')
                continue;
            node[i] = getSymbol(playerNum);
            int value = miniMax(node, 2); 
            if(value < bestVal)
            {
                bestVal = value;
                bestSpot = i;
            }
            node[i] = '-';
        }
        return bestSpot;
    }
}
```

And my score function

```
private int Score(int gameState)
{
    if(gameState ==2) //O wins.
        return 10;
    else if(gameState==1) //X wins
        return -10;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I have a working AI that tries to block my move and win, however sometimes it is making non-intelligent choices for instance this is the output I get if my input read from console is 6,7,8 in that order. It does not attempt to block my win. But in other cases it does.

---

|   O  |   O  |      |

---

|      |      |      |

---

|   X  |   X  |   X  |

---

In my second attempt I tried 4,3 and it blocked my winning move.

---

|      |   O  |      |

---

|   X  |   X  |   O  |

---

|      |      |      |

---

I was wondering anyone could point out what is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: You will probably get more advice at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

The behavior of the code for the shown examples is correct!

So why is the threat in the following position not blocked? Why does the program play move 1 instead of 6?

```
O . .                                    O 1 2
. . .     numbering available moves:     3 4 5
X X .                                    X X 6
```

*It is because if the game is lost on perfect play the program just plays the first available move.*

The algorithm only cares about win or loss and not in how many moves.

See what happens if the threat is blocked:

```
O . .     O . .
. . .     . X .     and X wins on his next move
X X O     X X O
```

Comment: The thing is that if the AI was playing a perfect game he would never lose a tic tac toe. He would go even. When X player played on the furthermore left-down corner the AI(if it was optimal) would play at the center. Thus preventing a potential loss. Now i dont now where the error is but definetely there is one.