# Minimax debugging. Not sure how to look for where the code is falling apart

Tags: java, swing, tic-tac-toe, minimax

First time actually using the site so if I do anything wrong I apologize in advance and will work to correct it given guidance. I am currently working on my senior project. It is a game very similar to tic-tac-toe but the height and width of the board are of variable sizes and the amount in a row needed to win is also variable (all chosen by the user through jcomboboxes).

the problem is that the miniMax method will often select a tile that's already been chosen. I'm not entirely sure how to figure out the source of the problem, after having done quite a few hours of research. I just need to be pointed in the right direction on the means of finding the source but will gladly take any help I can get

attached below is the code. I provided all of the code for the program so that it can be compiled and tested, hopefully, with ease. If this is the wrong thing to do I apologize, let me know and I will correct.

I found various examples of the minimax algorithm being implemented and ended up using the one in the following link: [simplest MiniMax algorithm for TicTacToe AI in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168697/simplest-minimax-algorithm-for-tictactoe-ai-in-java)

I also tried implementing the following: https://medium.com/@pelensky/unbeatable-tic-tac-toe-minimax-in-java-e1ad687ed821

but that led to numerous stackoverflow errors that I couldn't see how to reasonably mitigate without redoing the entire algorithm.

I am currently working with the former and it works to an extent but the AI doesn't appear to make intelligent decisions and will often try to choose a tile that's already been selected.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Konnexion extends JPanel
{
    ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>(); 
    private static int totalButtons;
    private JLabel winStat;
    private JLabel lossStat;
    protected JLabel drawStat;
    JPanel gameBoard;
    JButton exitButton;
    int wins = 0;
    int losses = 0;
    int draws = 0;
    Game game;


    public Konnexion(int height, int width, int connects, String ai)
    {
      JPanel gameStats = new JPanel();
      gameStats.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
      winStat = new JLabel("Wins: " + wins);
      lossStat = new JLabel("Losses: " + losses + " ");
      drawStat = new JLabel("Draws: " + draws);
      gameStats.add(winStat);
      gameStats.add(lossStat);
      gameStats.add(drawStat);
      add(gameStats);

          totalButtons = (height * width) - 1;
          gameBoard = new JPanel();
      gameBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(height,width));
      initializebuttons();
      add(gameBoard);

      JPanel menuButtons = new JPanel();
      menuButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
      exitButton = new JButton();
      exitButton.setText("Exit Game");
      exitButton.addActionListener(new buttonListener());
      menuButtons.add(exitButton);
      add(menuButtons);

      game = new Game(totalButtons, height, width, connects, ai);
    }

    public void initializebuttons()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= totalButtons; i++)
        {
                buttons.add(i, new JButton());
                buttons.get(i).setText("");
                buttons.get(i).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
            buttons.get(i).addActionListener(new buttonListener());

            gameBoard.add(buttons.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void resetButtons()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= totalButtons; i++)
        {
            buttons.get(i).setText("");
        }
        game.resetGameState();
    }

    private class buttonListener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            JButton buttonClicked = (JButton)e.getSource(); //get the particular button that was clicked
            if (buttonClicked.getText().equals(""))
            {

                    buttonClicked.setText(Game.getSymbol(game.getCurrentPlayer()));
                game.setMarker(buttons.indexOf(buttonClicked), game.getSymbol(game.getCurrentPlayer()));
                if (Game.getSymbol(game.getCurrentPlayer()).equals("X")) 
                {
                                game.changeCurrentPlayer();
                        if (game.hasWon("X", Game.cells)) {
                                wins++;
                                winStat.setText("Wins: " + wins);
                            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Player X Wins!!!");
                            resetButtons();
                            game.resetGameState();
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                            game.changeCurrentPlayer();
                        if (game.hasWon("O", Game.cells)) {
                                losses++;
                                lossStat.setText("Losses: " + losses + " ");
                        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Player O Wins!!!");
                        resetButtons();
                        game.resetGameState();
                    }
                }

                if (game.getCurrentPlayer() == 2) {
                        game.printArrays();
                        game.copyGameState();
                        //System.out.println(game.miniMax(game.getCurrentPlayer()));
                        buttons.get(game.miniMax(game.getCurrentPlayer())).doClick();
                }
            }
            else if (buttonClicked.equals(exitButton))
            {
                    Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(exitButton);
                    window.dispose();
                    try {
                        new MainMenu();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(buttonClicked, "That tile has already been selected!");
            }

            if (game.checkDraw())
            {
                    draws++;
                    drawStat.setText("Draws: " + draws);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "It was a Draw!!!");
                resetButtons();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Game {
    public static int ROWS;
    public static int COLS;
    public static int WIN_SIZE;
    public static int currentPlayer;
    public static String[][] cells; //Game state array
    String[][] node; //copy of the game state used for minimax method

    public Game(int totalButtons, int height, int width, int connects, String difficulty) {
        ROWS = height;
        COLS = width;
        WIN_SIZE = connects;
        currentPlayer = 1;
        cells = new String[ROWS][COLS];
        node = new String[ROWS][COLS];
        resetGameState(cells);
        resetGameState(node);
    }

    public void setMarker(int space, String marker) {
        int col = space % COLS;
        int rows = space / COLS;
        cells[rows][col] = marker;
    }

    public void changeCurrentPlayer() {
        if (currentPlayer == 1)
        {
            currentPlayer = 2;
        }
        else if (currentPlayer == 2)
        {
            currentPlayer = 1;
        }
    }

    public int getCurrentPlayer() {
            return currentPlayer;
    }

    public static String getSymbol(int playerNum) {
        if (playerNum == 1)
            return "X";
        else
            return "O";
    }

    public void resetGameState() {
        currentPlayer = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
                cells[i][j] = "-";
            }
        }
    }

    public static void resetGameState(String[][] gameState) {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameState[i].length; j++) {
                gameState[i][j] = "-";
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param theSeed   Value expected in each cell
     * @param row       Row index to check
     * @param col       Col index to check
     * @param count     Number of consecutive elements found in the line. 
     * @param rowIncrement   Increment to the row index for the next evaluation
     * @param colIncrement   Increment to the col index for the next evaluation
     * @return  true if there is a winner combination in the line, otherwise false. 
     */ 
    private boolean checkLine(String theSeed, int row, int col, int count, int rowIncrement, int colIncrement, String[][] gameCheck) {
        if (!areValidIndexes(row, col)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (theSeed.equals(gameCheck[row][col])) {
            count++;
            if (count >= WIN_SIZE) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return checkLine(theSeed, row + rowIncrement, col + colIncrement, count, rowIncrement, colIncrement, gameCheck);
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private boolean areValidIndexes(int row, int col) {
        if (row >= 0 && row < ROWS &&
            col >= 0 && col < COLS) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkRow(String theSeed, int row, int col, String[][] gameCheck) {
        return checkLine(theSeed, row, col, 0, 1, 0, gameCheck);
    }

    private boolean checkColumn(String theSeed, int row, int col, String[][] gameCheck) {
        return checkLine(theSeed, row, col, 0, 0, 1, gameCheck);
    }

    private boolean checkForwardDiagonal(String theSeed, int row, int col, String[][] gameCheck) {
        return checkLine(theSeed, row, col, 0, 1, 1, gameCheck);
    }

    private boolean checkBackwardDiagonal(String theSeed, int row, int col, String[][] gameCheck) {
        return checkLine(theSeed, row, col, 0, -1, 1, gameCheck);
    } 

    public boolean hasWon(String theSeed, String[][] gameCheck) {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                if (checkRow(theSeed, row, col, gameCheck) ||
                    checkColumn(theSeed, row, col, gameCheck) ||
                    checkForwardDiagonal(theSeed, row, col, gameCheck) ||
                    checkBackwardDiagonal(theSeed, row, col, gameCheck)) {

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkDraw()
    {
            String s = "";
        for (String[] r : cells) {
            for (String t : r) {
                s += t;
            }
        }

            if (!s.contains("-"))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
    }

    public static boolean checkDraw(String[][] node)
    {
            String s = "";
        for (String[] r : node) {
            for (String t : r) {
                s += t;
            }
        }

            if (!s.contains("-"))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
    }


    public int checkWin(String[][] gameState) {
        if (hasWon("X", gameState))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (hasWon("O", gameState))
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void copyGameState() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
                node[i][j] = cells[i][j];
            }
        }
    }


    public static int[] getAvailableSpaces() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
                if (cells[i][j].equals("-"))
                    s += ((j * COLS) + i) + ", ";
            }
        }
        String[] split = s.split(", ");

        int[] availableSpaces = new int[split.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
            availableSpaces[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);

        return availableSpaces;
    }

    public void resetSpace(int space) {
        int col = space % COLS;
        int rows = space / COLS;
        cells[rows][col] = "-";
    }


    public int miniMax(int playerNum)
    {
        //printArrays();
        int victor = checkWin(cells); // returns 0 if game is ongoing, 1 for p1, 2 for p2, 3 for tie.
        if(victor != 0) //game over
            {
            return Score(victor);
            }

        if(playerNum == 2) //AI
        {
            int bestVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int bestSpot = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++)
                    {
                        if(!cells[i][j].equals("-"))
                            continue;
                        cells[i][j] = getSymbol(playerNum);
                        int value = miniMax(1); 
                        if(value < bestVal)
                        {
                            bestVal = value;
                            bestSpot = (j * COLS) + i;
                            System.out.println("Best Value: " + bestVal);
                            System.out.println("Best Spot: " + bestSpot);
                        }

                        cells[i][j] = "-";
                    }
            return bestSpot;
        }
        else
        {
            int bestVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int bestSpot = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
                    for(int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++)
                    {
                        if(!cells[i][j].equals("-"))
                            continue;
                        cells[i][j] = getSymbol(playerNum);
                        int value = miniMax(2); 
                        if(value > bestVal)
                        {
                            bestVal = value;
                            bestSpot = (j * COLS) + i;
                        }
                        cells[i][j] = "-";
                    }
            return bestSpot;
        }
    }

    private int Score(int gameState)
    {
        if(gameState ==2) //O wins.
            return 10;
        else if(gameState==1) //X wins
            return -10;
        return 0;
    }

    public void printArrays() {
        String s = "cells: ";
        String l = "node: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <cells[i].length; j++) {
                s += cells[i][j];
                l += node[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) *"attached below is the code. I provided all of the code .. If this is the wrong thing to do I apologize, let me know and I will correct."* For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). An MCVE / SSCCE should best have only one `public` class, with the `main` method, with all other classes default access and pasted in directly after it. Remove all the cruft you can, before the error disappears. For example. I doubt the `SettingsPanel` has anything to do with the problem. Remove it from the MCVE / SSCCE.

Comment: 2) *"The project is to be presented at 11am today so while I think it's unlikely i'll have it solved by then.."* I think you're right, there.  *"I'm rather desperate."* It's actually more optimal to never mention either that or time constraints. It makes the reader more likely to think *"too late to help, might as well abandon this to provide help to people with better time management"*. 3) *"As for the problem.."* I've read that section several times and still do not understand what the problem is. Please sum it up in one sentence.

Comment: .. oh wait, I see it now *"AI doesn't appear to make intelligent decisions and will often try to choose a tile that's already been selected."* 4) *"I'm not entirely sure how to figure out the source of the problem"* Have you tried stepping through the code in debug mode? See also the [Debug Strategy](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/debug/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I appreciate the help. I have made your suggested edits to my question. The debug mode could definitely help! I'll do some reading on it, thank you.